# Avoid strong reference cycle in Block, can I simply do this

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am reading the book, it says:
To break the strong reference cycle, you declare a __weak pointer outside the block that points to self. Then you can use this pointer inside the block instead of self:

```
__weak BNREmployee *weakSelf = self; // a weak reference
myBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"Employee: %@", weakSelf);
};
```

The block’s reference to the BNREmployee instance is now a weak one, and the strong reference cycle is broken.
However, because the reference is weak, the object that self points to could be deallocated while the block is executing.
You can eliminate this risk by creating a strong local reference to self inside the block:

```
__weak BNREmployee *weakSelf = self; // a weak reference
myBlock = ^{
    BNREmployee *innerSelf = weakSelf; // a block-local strong reference
    NSLog(@"Employee: %@", innerSelf);
};
```

Why I cannot simply do the following?

```
myBlock = ^{
    BNREmployee *innerSelf = self; // a block-local strong reference
    NSLog(@"Employee: %@", innerSelf);
};
```

or

```
BNREmployee *strongSelf = self; 
myBlock = ^{
    BNREmployee *innerSelf = strongSelf; // a block-local strong reference
    NSLog(@"Employee: %@", innerSelf);
};
```

Comment: In the last two variants the block captures a strong variable which means you get a reference cycle. The block _must_ capture a weak variable to avoid the cycle. And very, very much _should_ assign it to a strong variable for consistent behaviour (the strong variable _may_ be nil if the weak variable was nil when it was assigned, but the strong variable will not change to the end of the block).

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks, what do you mean by the strong variable will not change to the end of the block? Could you explain that a bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your replacement block directly references `self`, so ARC will retain `self` as long as the block exists. If the block is retained by a property of the same object, you have a retain loop.

Comment: Then How about: BNREmployee *strongSelf = self; 
myBlock = ^{
    BNREmployee *innerSelf = strongSelf; // a block-local strong reference
    NSLog(@"Employee: %@", innerSelf);
};

Comment: `strongSelf` is strong, so when the block is copied (which it will be), the compiler will add an `objc_retain(strongSelf)`. That will add a retain to `self`, which will create your reference cycle. This problem is not solvable without a weak reference somewhere.

Comment: thanks. But in the original example it will also add a retain to self I think. the book says :By creating the strong innerSelf reference, you have again created a strong reference cycle between the block and the BNREmployee instance. But because the innerSelf reference is local to the scope of the block, the strong reference cycle will only exist while the block is executing and will be broken automatically when the block ends.

Comment: Is my understanding right? in the original example, self is retained by the block while it is running, while the block is not retained by self? but in my code both are retained by each other?_

Comment: In the original example, the compiler doesn't create a strong reference to self during copying the block (because the reference is weak). A strong reference is created only when the block is executed. In your code, because there is a strong reference inside the block to a strong reference outside the block, the compiler will add an extra strong reference during the copy. The difference is that in the BNR example, `innerSelf` has a strong reference. In yours, `innerSelf` has a strong reference and *the block itself* has a strong reference.

Comment: @bean: A block holds a copy of all (non-`__block`) captured variables (you can think of them as sort of "instance variables" of the block object). In the first and third cases, the block holds a `__strong` variable that point to the object pointed to by `self`. In the second case, the block holds a `__weak` variable that points to the object pointed to by `self`. That is the difference. (`self`, `weakSelf`, and `strongSelf` all point to the same object)

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks a lot. Just to confirm if my understanding is correct to your answer: A strong reference is created only when the block is executed. In your code, because there is a strong reference inside the block to a strong reference outside the block, the compiler will add an extra strong reference (to self)  during the copy. The difference is that in the BNR example, innerSelf has a strong reference. In yours, innerSelf has a strong reference and the block itself (I think the block has a strong reference in both case, should be self) has a strong reference.

Comment: @RobNapier, Sorry I find I myself misunderstand you in my previous reply. A strong reference is created only when the block is executed. In your code, because there is a strong reference inside the block to a strong reference outside the block, the compiler will add an extra strong reference (to self)  during the copy. The difference is that in the BNR example, innerSelf has a strong reference (to self). In yours, innerSelf has a strong reference (to self) and the block itself has a strong reference (to self).

Comment: See @newacct's comment for a clearer explanation (my discussion of copying is more confusing than his explanation). But the short form is that blocks can hold a reference to an object. If you refer, inside a block, to a strong variable that exists outside the block, then the block itself will hold a reference to that object, and the object will be kept around as long as the block exists. Blocks themselves are objects, and have their own lifetimes. If a block references something that references the block, there is a cycle.